# Regular expression for allowing negative values or zero

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, regex-lookarounds

Earlier I was using the regular expression as `/^-\d*(\.\d+)?$/` which was checking for negative decimal values, but now I want to add so that it will allow negative as well as zero in the field.

I tried to use OR condition based upon which it will allow zero value but was unsuccessful.

Please share ideas how can I improve this regular expression.

Comment: http://regexr.com/ is a really good place to work on regular expressions and test as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `/^-\d*(\.\d+)?$|^0$/` the pipe has higher priority over anchors or encapsulate it inside a non capture group:

```
^(?:-\d*(?:\.\d+)?|0)$
 ^^^              ^ ^
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
^(-\d*(\.\d+)?|0)$
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.